# Visual studio code EPERM Operation not permitted

Tags: visual-studio-code

Everytime I try and install a new extension onto vsc I get:

```
Error while loading extensions. EPERM: operation not permitted
```

followed by it telling me to open a .obsolete file. The file path it tells me too doesnt exist though. I do not have a .vscode folder for some reason.

Comment: Is this on Windows?

Comment: @GinoMempin yes

Answer (score 4):

- You should first go your current user "C:\Users\your_user_name"
  directory.
- Then click the "Hidden Items" checkbox.
- After you will see the ".vscode" folder.
- Last thing to do is deleting it and reopen the VS Code.

Comment: Following the steps has resolved my problem, thanks for your answer @kerem

Comment: Actually after the first bullet point, Once your in your "C:\Users\your_user_name dir **right click** this will open the **contextual menu** then select **Properties** a few tabs will pop up. You want the default which is **General** i.e. the one you'll be on automatically. From there under **Attribures** you'll se the **Hidden** checkbox...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when re-installing Visual Studio Code. The old .vscode folder with my old extensions persisted. Deleting the old .vscode folder solved the problem.

It may be hidden. To show hidden folders in File Explorer, go to View > check 'Hidden Items' in Show/hide section.

Answer (score 0):

1. Locate the .vscode folder on your computer and open
2. Open the extensions folder and scroll down to the "extensions.json" file and then delete the file
3. Restart your vs code and try installing or updating your extensions. It should work this time. This worked for me

Answer (score -1):

I tried removing the .vscode folder which didn't work.

It's a permission error.

1. Right click the shortcut of VSCode.
2. Go to properties.
3. Compatibility tab.
4. Check "Run this program as an administrator"
5. Restart and re-run your command.