# Installing python extension on VS Code returning error

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I recently installed VS Code. I created my first .py file and received the message/shortcut to install the python extension. When I click on install I get an error message saying "Error while installing 'Python' extension. I have tried reading the log, but it is not very clear to me. Any thoughts or tips?

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmG99.png)

[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzPw7.png)

Comment: Next time please consider adding the logs as a code block to facilitate readability. As a solution try with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60908817/10569220).

Comment: @NicoE I tried to, but apparently you have to have 10 badges to be able to use that feature and I just created my account... Seems like it should be a given feature.

Comment: try checking this [examples](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/880603), is actually a given feature an everyone can use it.

Comment: Could you install other packages? It looks like the file permission was locked.

Comment: @Steven I can add some extensions and not others.

Comment: @NicoE Have you reinstalled the VSCode before you run across this problem? And can you try to reload the VSCode with administrator permission? And make sure you can modify the folder and files under the related folder(c:\users\....\.vscode; c:\users\..\appdata\local\programs\microsfot vscode\resource\....; the folder in the image)?

Comment: @texRanger009 Hi friend, have you solve the problem?

Comment: @Steven Yes, I was able to install the needed packages. Not sure what fixed it though. I tried a bunch of different things and nothing worked so I left it for a little and worked on some other stuff. When I came back to try again it worked. so idk

Comment: got it, sounds good, friend.